# Change a Script to a For Do Done Loop

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, awk

I have a script that I need to turn into a loop, the script works exactly as I need it to (My Awk-fu is extremely weak, so be nice) when I put in the file name like the example below.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v FS='(<LastName>|<\/LastName>)' '{print $2}' 17822624.xml >> test.csv
awk -v FS='(<FirstName>|<\/FirstName>)' '{print $2}' 17822624.xml >> test.csv
awk -v FS='(<Id>|<\/Id>)' '{print $2}' 17822624.xml >> test.csv
awk -v FS='(<Dob>|<\/Dob>)' '{print $2}' 17822624.xml >> test.csv
awk -v FS='(<TestDate>|<\/TestDate>)' '{print $2}' 17822624.xml >> test.csv
#this awk command is different because their are multiple different values i need it to pull back
awk -F '<Value>|<\/Value>' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}' 17822624.xml >> test.csv
cat test.csv | tr '\n' ',' > test2.csv
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=','} {sub(/ ..:..:..$/,'')} !seen[$0]++' test2.csv > test3.csv
```

When I convert it to a for do done loop is when I'm having problems. I believe it is related to Single Quotes vs double quotes and ) vs {. but I'm trying a lot of different things with out luck.

Here is the loop I created

```
#!/bin/bash
#file location
XMLDIR='/home/amoore19/XML/00581-001/scores'
NEWXML='/home/amoore19/XML/00581-001'

#this gives me the filenames without the path
for file in `ls ${XMLDIR}/*.xml | xargs -n1 basename`
do
awk -v FS='(<LastName>|<\/LastName>)' '{print $2}' "${XMLDIR}/${file}" >> "${NEWXML}/${file}"
awk -v FS='(<FirstName>|<\/FirstName>)' '{print $2}' "${XMLDIR}/${file}" >> "${NEWXML}/${file}"
awk -v FS='(<Id>|<\/Id>)' '{print $2}' "${XMLDIR}/${file}" >> "${NEWXML}/${file}"
awk -v FS='(<Dob>|<\/Dob>)' '{print $2}' "${XMLDIR}/${file}" >> "${NEWXML}/${file}"
awk -v FS='(<TestDate>|<\/TestDate>)' '{print $2}' "${XMLDIR}/${file}" >> "${NEWXML}/${file}"
awk -F '<Value>|<\/Value>' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}' "${XMLDIR}/${file}" >> "${NEWXML}/${file}"
"${NEWXML}/${file}" | tr '\n' ',' > "${NEWXML}/1${file}"
awk "BEGIN{RS=ORS=,} {sub(/..:..:..$/,"")} !seen[$0]++" "${NEWXML}/1${file}" > "${NEWXML}/2${file}"
done
```

This is the error I get: I have tried switching the single quotes for double with not much better luck

```
$ ./ifthen.sh 
ls: /home/amoore19/XML/00581-001/scores/*.xml: No such file or directory
basename: missing operand
Try `basename --help' for more information.
```

and like I said the top example works great, but i need to be able to loop through several files in a folder.

I know this is ugly, I know awk could do the whole thing in a loop by itself, but I don't know how to create that. one day I will, but for right now this is the best I can do and I could really use some help/guidance on whats wrong with my loop.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

I updated the code as far as I could after using shellcheck. still getting the error mentioned.

**New Update**

so I think I found my problem, but I don't understand why its a problem? I did a new bash script that simple does a cd to the directory and it still says it doesn't exist.  if I do it to just /home/amoore19/XML it works, but something about the folder name being 00581-001 is causing my problem...any ideas?

**LAST UPDATE**
I deleted the 00581-001 folder and recreated it and moved the files back in and I'm no longer getting the error...im guessing it somehow became corrupt? (I added an extra 0 to it by accident on recreation)

Here is the current working script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#file location
XMLDIR='/home/amoore19/XML/000581-001/scores'
NEWXML='/home/amoore19/XML/000581-001'

#this gives me the filenames without the path
for file in `ls ${XMLDIR}/*.xml | xargs -n1 basename`
do
awk -v FS='(<LastName>|<\/LastName>)' '{print $2}' "${XMLDIR}/${file}" >> "${NEWXML}/${file}"
awk -v FS='(<FirstName>|<\/FirstName>)' '{print $2}' "${XMLDIR}/${file}" >> "${NEWXML}/${file}"
awk -v FS='(<Id>|<\/Id>)' '{print $2}' "${XMLDIR}/${file}" >> "${NEWXML}/${file}"
awk -v FS='(<Dob>|<\/Dob>)' '{print $2}' "${XMLDIR}/${file}" >> "${NEWXML}/${file}"
awk -v FS='(<TestDate>|<\/TestDate>)' '{print $2}' "${XMLDIR}/${file}" >> "${NEWXML}/${file}"
awk -F '<Value>|<\/Value>' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}' "${XMLDIR}/${file}" >> "${NEWXML}/${file}"
"${NEWXML}/${file}" | tr '\n' ',' > "${NEWXML}/1${file}"
awk "BEGIN{RS=ORS=,} {sub(/..:..:..$/,"")} !seen[$0]++" "${NEWXML}/1${file}" > "${NEWXML}/2${file}"
done
```

Thanks everyone for the help, the shellcheck helped me know that my script wasn't wrong and then everyone else saying that the directory doesn't exist (even though i knew it did) helped me determine there was something wrong with the folder

Comment: check your code with http://shellcheck.net

Comment: wow that is awesome, I never heard of that before. Hopefully it helps, thank you

Comment: As shellcheck no doubt has told you shell variables don't expand inside single quoted strings (though its reporting of that is less than helpful with `awk` as it isn't smart enough, apparently, to tell the difference between the awk script itself and the file arguments to awk). As additional best practices see: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs , http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor , and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001.

Comment: That being said those aren't the problem in your script but I also don't see the problem that the shell is complaining about... are you sure that's the *exact* script that causes the problem?

Comment: yes it is the exact code

Comment: The error says there are no `.xml` files in `/home/amoore19/XML/00581-001/scores/`. Can you check that? Can you give the absolute path to a file you believe should match?

Comment: that is what is so confusing to me, there are 5 xml files in that folder

Comment: it acting like the *.xml is a literal item instead of a variable

Comment: even when i get rid of the *.xml its acting like that directory doesn't exist...but it does

Comment: so I think I found my problem, but I don't understand why its a problem? I did a new bash script that simple does a cd to the directory and it still says it doesn't exist. something about the folder name being 00581-001 is causing my problem...any ideas?

Comment: I would highly recommend using actual XML parsing tools for parsing XML - `awk` and other line/record-oriented tools aren't the best suited for the job...

Comment: twalberg, I agree, learning to do that is on my list. but my deadline is to close for me to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the code wasn't invalid (had to correct some quoting issues) but that the folder was corrupt when i tried to use it in the bash script. Here is the working code with the correct double quotes around the directory variables.

```
#!/bin/bash
#file location
XMLDIR='/home/amoore19/XML/00581-001/scores'
NEWXML='/home/amoore19/XML/00581-001'

#this gives me the filenames without the path
for file in `ls ${XMLDIR}/*.xml | xargs -n1 basename`
do
awk -v FS='(<LastName>|<\/LastName>)' '{print $2}' "${XMLDIR}/${file}" >> "${NEWXML}/${file}"
awk -v FS='(<FirstName>|<\/FirstName>)' '{print $2}' "${XMLDIR}/${file}" >> "${NEWXML}/${file}"
awk -v FS='(<Id>|<\/Id>)' '{print $2}' "${XMLDIR}/${file}" >> "${NEWXML}/${file}"
awk -v FS='(<Dob>|<\/Dob>)' '{print $2}' "${XMLDIR}/${file}" >> "${NEWXML}/${file}"
awk -v FS='(<TestDate>|<\/TestDate>)' '{print $2}' "${XMLDIR}/${file}" >> "${NEWXML}/${file}"
awk -F '<Value>|<\/Value>' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}' "${XMLDIR}/${file}" >> "${NEWXML}/${file}"
"${NEWXML}/${file}" | tr '\n' ',' > "${NEWXML}/1${file}"
awk "BEGIN{RS=ORS=,} {sub(/..:..:..$/,"")} !seen[$0]++" "${NEWXML}/1${file}" > "${NEWXML}/2${file}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You may not have any XML files in that directory, so the shell expansion will just be `${XMLDIR}/*.xml`. You could try using `find` instead:

```
find ${XMLDIR}/*.xml -exec `basename` | while read file; do
...
...
done
```

Comment: when i replace :      for file in `ls ${XMLDIR}/*.xml | xargs -n1 basename` with:     find ${XMLDIR}/*.xml -exec `basename` | while read file;  
I get the following error: 

    basename: missing operand
    Try `basename --help' for more information.
    find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: not getting that error anymore after i fixed the bad folder problem, thank you for the help